# Hibernate: JOIN inheritance question - why the need for two left joins

Tags: sql, hibernate, join, hibernate-mapping

I've been reading an [article](https://thorben-janssen.com/complete-guide-inheritance-strategies-jpa-hibernate/) about inheritance strategies in Hibernate.

An `Author` has publications, and a `Publication` can be a `Book` or a `BlogPost`.
In the `join` inheritance strategy the following table structure is generated:

[image]

So the `publicationauthor` table stores two foreign keys: `authorid` and `publicationid`. The `publication` table stores the fields that are common to books and blogposts, and the `book` and `blogpost` store fields that are common only to the subclasses.

Then the article shows the SQL query generated when a `author.getPublications()` method is called:

```sql
select publicatio0_.authorId as authorId2_4_0_, publicatio0_.publicationId as 
publicat1_4_0_, publicatio1_.id as id1_3_1_, publicatio1_.publishingDate as 
publishi2_3_1_, publicatio1_.title as title3_3_1_, publicatio1_.version as version4_3_1_, 
publicatio1_1_.pages as pages1_2_1_, publicatio1_2_.url as url1_1_1_, 

case when 
publicatio1_1_.id is not null then 1 when publicatio1_2_.id is not null then 2 when 
publicatio1_.id is not null then 0 end as clazz_1_ 

from PublicationAuthor publicatio0_ 

inner join Publication publicatio1_ on publicatio0_.publicationId=publicatio1_.id 

left outer join Book publicatio1_1_ on publicatio1_.id=publicatio1_1_.id 

left outer join BlogPost publicatio1_2_ on publicatio1_.id=publicatio1_2_.id 

where publicatio0_.authorId=?
```

The SQL query first `inner join`s the `publicationauthor` and `publication`, so that each `Publication` gets an `authorid` from the `publicationauthor` table.

Then the result (which would have Books.length + BlogPosts.length number of rows) is `left outer` joined with `book` table, so that each publication that is a book gets the columns from the `book` table.

At this point the result looks something like this, the green rows are the rows that correspond to books and have the corresponding columns, the gray rows are the rows that didn't map to any `id` in the `book` table and thus only have `authorid` column and columns from the `publication` table filled.

[image]

Then we do the second `left outer join` to join the result with the `blogpost` table. This is the way I imagine what's going on here: the cartesian product is created: each row in the result table is mapped to all rows in the `blogpost` table (orange rows):

[image]

Then each row from the result table (green and gray) is compared by `id` with the orange row, and if there's a match, the columns from the `blogpost` row are added to the result table for the matching row.

However, as can be seen from the example, most of the result table is green rows - books, which by definition wouldn't be able to find a matching row in the `blogpost` table, yet we perform the comparison many times over regardless.

Wouldn't it be more efficient to only make the cartesian product of the gray and orange rows, like this:

[image]

If we assume we have a million books and only one blogpost, wouldn't it enhance performace dramatically? The way I see it, once we've joined the books, we could isolate the gray rows and join them with `blogpost` separately, and then perhaps use a kind of a union operation to get the final result table?

Is there something I'm not seeing/understanding here?

Comment: Yes, there are lots of ways to write SQL queries that give the same resultset. How each one performs depends on lots of factors: data volumes, indexing, etc. Also, as SQL is a descriptive language, how you write a SQL statement doesn’t necessarily correlate to how the query optimiser will execute it. I’m possibly not really getting what you are asking here?

Comment: @NickW Is it not true that query optimiser would **always** create a cartesian product of the green and orange rows? After all, it has no way of knowing that the `blogpost` table is guaranteed to not have any rows with IDs from the `book` table

Comment: As you don’t have any cartesian joins in your SQL query I’m not sure why you think anything is going to create a Cartesian product? It’s only selecting records that match on the ids. It will select the books and blogposts that match on the publication ids